# What gauge wire is this, and how can I tell?

Tags: wiring, gauge

Can someone tell me how to determine the gauge of this wire (circled in red), or just what gauge it is?

[image]

Comment: Is there no information printed or stamped on it? Looks like a #6 to me, which would be appropriate for that breaker (at least in copper). Otherwise, a wire gauge... gauge has a set of holes for sizing.

Comment: Usually the gauge is printed on the outside of the insulation somewhere, and is repeated along the length of the cable. Trace the wire back and see if you can find that info. Looks like aluminum to me, based on the silver color right as it enters the terminal in the breaker.

Comment: But it looks like it might be a 12 gauge going into a 50 amp breaker below it, which is scary.

Comment: Can you add another photo or two of this panel please? I'm wondering if something else is up with this panel of yours...

Comment: Somewhat off topic, but are those huge gouges in the insulation of all the black wires at the bottom?  It looks like they all have big cuts along them.

Comment: Maybe not gouges but places with adhering dust wiped off?